# AWS DNS settings not working for email

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, email, amazon-route53

I appreciate how difficult this is likely to be to diagnose so I'll supply as much detail as possible.

I have registered the domain name `staplefitzpaine.com` with AWS and set up the hosted zone records the same way I have with other domains whose email works fine.

The hosted zone records are set up as recommended by Fasthosts and appear as follows:
[image]

The email account is set up on Fasthosts in the same way that my other email addresses are set up.

However email to this domain is being rejected.

A check on https://intodns.com/staplefitzpaine.com gives the following errors, suggesting an issue with the DNS:

[image]

I have tried removing the hosted zone completely and re-adding but the result is the same.

I'd really appreciate some suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your registrar lists your nameservers as **ns1.nameservers.co.uk** and **ns1.nameservers.co.uk**, but you're using Amazon instead. So you need to set those nameservers that Amazon uses with your registrar first, so that the .com TLD nameservers knows where to send queries for **staplefitzpaine.com**

The reason you get all those errors is that **ns1.nameservers.co.uk** and **ns2.nameservers.co.uk** has never heard of the domain **staplefitzpaine.com** so they of course don't respond with anything.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help! :)